# How set username to ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I want to set value, but i don't know how do it.
Error:

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /comments/
> commentsTabl has no avtor.
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/comments/
> Django Version: 4.0.2
> Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
> Exception Value:
> commentsTabl has no avtor.
> Exception Location: D:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py, line 197, in **get**
> Python Executable:  D:\python39\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.9.6
> Python Path:
> ['D:\Django\ForumXT\first',
> 'D:\python39\python39.zip',
> 'D:\python39\DLLs',
> 'D:\python39\lib',
> 'D:\python39',
> 'D:\python39\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:    Thu, 07 Apr 2022 12:20:35 +0000

models.py

```
class commentsTabl(models.Model):
    Text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='date')
    avtor = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='avtor', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="username")

     def __str__(self):
         return f'Comment {self.avtor} at {self.date}'

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = "Comment"
         verbose_name_plural = "Comments"
```

views.py

```
def comments(request):
     data = {
         'com': reversed(commentsTabl.objects.all())
     }
     if request.method =="POST":
         form = commentsTabl(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
     else:
         form = commentsTabl()
     return render(request, 'home/comments.html', data, {'form':form})
```

Comment: Temporarily just put ```avtor = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='avtor', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="username", blank=True, null=True)``` and then run ```python manage.py makemigrations``` and then ```python manage.py migrate```

Comment: It doesn't work. I do it and my data base of comments is lost

Comment: Remove to field from model

Comment: I do this too. But i Have Error: 'commentsTabl' object has no attribute 'avtor'

Comment: I think it might be erroring on you `__str__`.  Try removing self.avatar from that and see if it works.  if it does, add `blank=True, null=True` to the field definition

Comment: I deleted. But my html document not reading...
It's reading how standart txt...

Comment: I fixed this and try deleted self.avtor.
It not working(

Comment: CommentsTabl has no avtor. Anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    Text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True, verbose_name='date')
    avtor = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='avtor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} at {}'.format(self.avtor, self.date)

    class Meta:
        # Order comments in reverse order
        # ordering = ["-id"]
```

## In views.py

```
from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import Comments
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


def comments(request):
    # Retrive all comments from database
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    # Reverse ...
    comments = reversed(comments)

    # Form with no data (unbound form)
    form = CustomerForm()
    context = {"comments": comments, "form": form}
    # when method is post
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Don't save the form to database
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            # Add user to the comment
            comment.avtor = request.user
            # Save comment to database
            comment.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some url name'))
        
        # when form is invalid
        else:
            # Re-render the form with errors and data
            context["form"] = form
            return render(request, "home/comments.html", context)

    # when method is not post
    else:
        return render(request, "home/comments.html", context)
```

## In forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment

# Create your forms here
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ("Text", "date",)
        # or
        # exclude = ("avtor",)
        # fields = "__all__"
```

## Important

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`
3. In comments.html you will have access to `form` and `comments`

Comment: Thanks, form is working!!! But form doesn't save in database(((